# How to update columns in a table for specific rows?

Tags: mysql

I want to update my columns for rows specified by `WHERE` command, but I want to update my field in a way that it extracts number part of the string from each specified field, multiplies that with a number (that I will specify) and give number output in all those specific fields extracted by WHERE command in that column.

For example, assume I want to update all my fields in a column which are like `(5.6 AUD/1000, 4.5 AUD/1000, 9.7 AUD/1000)`, so I want to first identify fields ending with `/1000` and update only those fields in the column by multiplying the number part of the string (which is 5.6, 4.5, 9.7) with any number (let's say 10). I want that other fields on the column remains unchanged.

```
SELECT * from sorted WHERE Column8  REGEXP '/1000$';
```

gives me all the specific fields that I wish to update. But I want to update them in the way I specified above, which is that I want to extract number part from the string and multiply that with a number and update those fields only.

I am able to extract all the fields with the condition I mentioned, I'm facing difficulty in update these fields in the column.

SELECT * from sorted WHERE Column8  REGEXP '/1000$';

```
SELECT CAST(Column8 AS UNSIGNED)*10 FROM sorted
wHERE
 column8 REGEXP '/1000$';
```

The above code gives me required updated fields, but I want them reflected in my column.

I expect my output to be a column where only those fields ending with '/1000' should get updated in a way that the number part of the string is multiplied with 10.

Comment: A bit pedantic but 5.6 is not an integer,

Comment: @P.Salmon I corrected it now, thanks for pointing out :)

Comment: see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 0):

I have casted the `varchar` field named string to decimal type and multiplied with static value 10  . I have checked in sql server.

```
DECLARE @temp TABLE
(
  string NVARCHAR(50)
)

INSERT INTO @temp (string)
VALUES 
('5.6 AUD/1000'),
('4.5 AUD/1000'),
('9.7 AUD/1000')

select cast(left(string, patindex('%[^0-9./]%', string) - 1) As decimal(18,2))* 10
from @temp
```

Comment: @harjot Singh did u get the solution??

Comment: The three strings are not manually input. I have to extract specific fields based on WHERE condition, and then apply multiplication on only the number part of the extracted string, and then update the column, keeping all other field values,which don't fall under WHERE command unchanged.

Comment: @HarjotSingh use sql procedure .create a temp table where you can store the results from the WHERE clause,then apply the mentioned query from the temp table